# MySql - Generating a Cartesian product of a single table

Tags: mysql, self-join, cartesian-product, cartesian

I have a single table "Data" in my MySQL database. This contains the following structure:

```
CID | CVALUE
------------------
1   | 1A
1   | 1B
1   | 1C
2   | 2A
2   | 2B
3   | 3A
4   | 4A
4   | 4B
4   | 4C
5   | 5A
5   | 5B
```

I need a cartesian product that contains all the combinations of CVALUE column. Hence I use the below query which refers to the same table with multiple aliases to treat them as different tables.

```
select a.cvalue, b.cvalue, c.cvalue, d.cvalue, e.cvalue
from data a, data b, data c, data d, data e
where a.cid = 1 and b.cid = 2 and c.cid = 3 and d.cid = 4 and e.cid = 5;
```

The above query works, and I am able to get a result set as below

```
cvalue | cvalue | cvalue | cvalue | cvalue
--------------------------------------------
1A     | 2A     | 3A     | 4A     | 5A
1A     | 2A     | 3A     | 4A     | 5B
1A     | 2A     | 3A     | 4B     | 5A
1A     | 2A     | 3A     | 4B     | 5B
1A     | 2A     | 3A     | 4C     | 5A
1A     | 2A     | 3A     | 4C     | 5B
.... and so on for the remaining combinations.
```

The problem with this approach is that I am not sure how many unique CID values I will have, and it gets cumbersome to add the column entries manually in the query, as well as add alias to the same table.

I was wondering if there is any query or function that can be used in MYSQL to generate such a cartesian product of a single table. Any help or pointers in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL has no support for hierarchical or recursive queries.  You can do this, but it requires dynamic SQL . . . or perhaps a looping structure with temporary tables.

Comment: I think it's possible with a very ugly construct of `SET`, `FOR` and `COUNT` with some subselects. But it's too much logic for a database, tho.